# Truncated incorrect double value ''

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

It is my mysql code ;

```
    INSERT INTO tablomusteriabonebilgileri (
    ID,
    StartDate,
    EndDate
)
VALUES
    (
        0,
        CASE '17-05-2017'
    WHEN '' THEN
        NULL
    WHEN LENGTH('17-05-2017') < 6 THEN
        NULL
    ELSE
        CONVERT (
            STR_TO_DATE('17-05-2017', '%e-%c-%Y'),
            CHAR (50)
        )
    END,
    CASE '17-05-2017'
WHEN '' THEN
    NULL
WHEN LENGTH('17-05-2017') < 6 THEN
    NULL
ELSE
    CONVERT (
        STR_TO_DATE('17-05-2017', '%e-%c-%Y'),
        CHAR (50)
    )
END
    )
```

but i get the error like this

> Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '17-05-2017'

Is there any mistake ? I didn't find anything.

Comment: Are you sure that you've defined StartDate and EndDate as datatype Date in your table?

Comment: yes sir they are date

Comment: If I was going there, I wouldn't start from here. :-(

Comment: @Strawberry it's an example sir....

Answer (score 0):

I got similar error "Truncated incorrect double value : 'USD". I defined my fields as decimal but i was trying to insert currency key into decimal fields . So i was getting this error . After that i corrected inserting correct values into respective fields then it got resolved .

Comment: Hi Naresh - could you please edit this to show how to do this in the case of the code in the question?